# Dependency not showing in Dependency Tree but is included in WAR

Tags: maven, dependencies, war, slf4j

I'm currently having some issues with logging in a WAR file I'm building using Maven. When I try to access the servlets in the WAR, I get an error from SLF4J caused by a '[delegation loop](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop)'.

To fix this, I understand that I need to remove one of the libraries (`slf4j-log4j12` in my case), which I should be able to do by excluding it in the POM (I'm not explicitly including any logging apart from `slf4j-api`).

However, `slf4j-log4j12` isn't showing up in the dependency tree - either through the Dependency Hierarchy tab in Eclipse or through the `dependency:tree` goal. When I look inside the WAR file though, `slf4j-log4j12.jar` is present in the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Any ideas why the dependency isn't showing up in the dependency tree? Are there any other ways that the JAR could be getting included in the build?

Comment: Have you update your maven project ? have you refresh the project also before looking Inside the war ?

Comment: Yes, the project is up to date and I've rebuilt the WAR several times from the latest version of the project.

Comment: The 'mvn dependency:tree' command is your friend.

Comment: @Ceki, as you'll see from above I tried that and according to that none of the dependencies I have are including `slf4j-log4j12.jar`, yet it is still appearing in the compiled WAR.

Comment: @JamesBaker The 'mvn dependency:tree'  is more reliable than the dependency tree provided by Eclipse. For all questions involving dependency mysteries, 'mvn dependency:tree' is the way to go.

Comment: @Ceki - I tried both, and they showed the same thing.

Comment: Please include above the output produced by 'mvn dependency:tree'. Remove or edit parts which you deem confidential.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. servlet-api.2.3 stays in my dependencies even though the dependency tree says it isn't included :(

Comment: Could be that the jar is included because it is used in a plugin

Answer (score 0):

I used in my project an old version for `log4j` and `slf4j` and that worked without any problem. 
Try to modify your jars in the `pom.xml` like this : if this worked you can modify the version with your choice :

For **slf4j** :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

For **log4j** :

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.9</version>
 </dependency>
```